# NODE.JS local host refused connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I'm trying to learn some back-end web development on my own and I'm having a slight issue with  starting a local server. Below, I will provide the code I have and screen shots of the error I'm receiving in the terminal when I attempt to connect.

FYI: I'm on windows 10, using VS code, I have installed Node.js.
Also, I'm following a video tutorial by Web Dev Simplified. The Video is "Your First Node.js Web Server"

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res)
{
res.write('hello node')
res.end()
})

server.listen(port,function(error)
{
    if(error)
    {   
        console.log('Something went wrong', error)

    }
    else
    {
        console.log('server is listening on port ' + port)

    }
})
```

Image of server start up.

[image]

and now the image of the errors.

[image]

this is what the chrome localhost:3000 is showing when I try to connect.

[image]

I really appreciate the time anyone would take to help a noob like me!

Comment: Just a quick comment.... I do know that there are many questions similar to this but none have been able to provide an answer that resolved the problem. Most were poorly written.

Comment: Looks like you didn't save your code or that you execute a different file. You code shows `res.write('hello node')` the error message says `Response.write('hello node')`.

Comment: If you show error messages (or any other textual content) then please don't post them as images but as text. It is really annoying to type an error to search for it. Besides that this site is also used by people that might be handicapped and don't see well or are blind.

Comment: Your code works without any issue.
As @t.niese mentioned check your file again it's issue with the mentioned reference 
http.createServer(function(req, res)
{
res.write('hello node')
res.end()
})

Or 

http.createServer(function(req, Response)
{
Response.write('hello node')
Response.end()
})

Comment: okay, it is working for me now! I thought I saved the change but I guess not lol. Also, I will avoid posting screenshots from now on. Thank you for letting me know.